# Install linux dual boot without a bootable media

Tags: linux

I have one Linux flavor installed on a laptop. Now I am at the desktop of this system, with a different Linux ISO downloaded and got sufficient free disk space.

From here, is it possible to install the downloaded Linux directly into the free hard disk space, creating a dual boot setup?

Comment: You would need to arrange enough unallocated space on the disk for new partition(s) for the second installation.

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc. Yes, as mentioned in the question, sufficient free space is available

Comment: Is the problem booting the second Linux from the ISO and without using bootable USB?

Comment: Yes, need to install a second Linux on free partition, without using a bootable media.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/989918/install-linux-dual-boot-without-a-bootable-media/989928#989928 ? I don't know, if I should copy that answer here.

Comment: Hi @NikitaKipriyanov, yes, that was on Server Fault site. I was asked to repost it here by the moderators. According to them, the question was not relevant to a production server environment.

Comment: Which system do you have and which one do you want to install?

Comment: I have Deepin and plan to install Parrot OS.

Comment: @Chaminda - While your question might have been closed, if your question was answered by the answer in question, as the author of the question you should have asked the question be migrated here.  *I would still suggest you make that question to the Server Fault moderators, so the two questions can be merged, so there is a single question with two answers*

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound. I flagged the thread with suggested concerns for the attention of moderators.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure for Ubuntu is described in the article
[How to Boot Linux ISO Images Directly From Your Hard Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/).

The not-so-simple procedure uses GRUB2 and is summarized below:

- To create a GRUB2 Boot Entry edit this file

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
  ```
- Add a new boot entry that may look like this (use your values):

  ```
  menuentry “Ubuntu 14.04 ISO” {
  set isofile=”/home/name/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso”
  loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  }
  ```
- Save the file and run the command:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- On the next boot you’ll see this boot entry and can choose it to boot
  the ISO file. You may have to hold Shift while booting to see the GRUB menu.

You may find more details and useful notes in the article itself.